# Test db not rolling back after each run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE: FIXED!!!!!
As I suspected it was a config that was messed up somehow - much hair pulling ensued. For some reason "require 'test_help'" was deleted from test_helper.rb, added it back in and all the tests are in a transaction now.

This smells like a basic config issue but I can't figure out what. Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7 patch 173. I am using Shoulda+factory girl and have a test for that creates a couple of users for setup

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase 
  use_transactional_fixtures = true
  context "getting a user's email" do 
    setup do
      ... stubs ...
    end

    should "populate email field if not present" do
      @user = Factory.create(:molly_perkins)
      @user.get_email(@facebook_session) 
      assert_equal 'molly.perkins.test@gmail.com', @user.email
    end

    should "not populate email if already present" do
      @user = Factory.create(:amanda_levy)
      @user.get_email(@facebook_session)
      assert_equal 'amandalevy06@gmail.com', @user.email
    end
  end
end
```

The tests pass, but problem is these don't seem to be cleared after running - looking at test.log, I see that the transactions commit the inserts! What gives?

```
  # First test
  User Create (0.3ms)   INSERT INTO `users` ...
  SQL (0.4ms)   COMMIT
  # Second test
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
  User Create (0.3ms)   INSERT INTO `users` ....
  SQL (0.4ms)   COMMIT
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
  User Update (0.4ms)   UPDATE `users` ....
  SQL (0.4ms)   COMMIT
```

To work around this I'm just using a teardown block of "Model.all.each(&:destroy)", but I shouldn't have to do that, and it's slow/janky to have to destroy everything I instantiate. The transactions should just rollback...

Table in the test DB is InnoDB:

```
mysql> select engine from tables where table_name = 'users' and table_schema = 'voltron_test';
+--------+
| engine |
+--------+
| InnoDB |
+--------+
```

and I'm using transactional fixtures (from test_helper.rb):

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Transactions do work (accessing test DB from console):

```
mysql> select * from users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO `users` ...
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from users;
   ...
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> ROLLBACK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you specifying the user ID in your factories?

Comment: yes, I am - although I just tweaked it and it doesn't make a difference whether or not the primary key is specified. Although the way I understand it, if the transaction is rolled back this shouldn't matter?

Comment: weird.  There's nowhere else where use_transactional_fixtures is being set to false, which is included or executed before your test?  Don't forget that tests are done in alphabetic order, not the order they're written in.

Comment: Stephen, I found I didn't have "require 'test_help'" in test_helper for whatever reason. Thanks for responding and getting my brain working, I marked your answer as the correct one so you can get the bounty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used the `use_transaction_fixtures = true` in the test case, but have alwsays had:

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
    ....
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    ....
end
```

in the test/test_helper.rb file that comes with Rails, and never had that problem.

Comment: thanks Stephen. Yeah I've got transactional_fixtures configured (and updated my Q with that info)

Comment: weird.  two thoughts:  tests aren't executed in the order you specify them, so could it being set to false in another test which is being executed first?  The other thing is can you prove that the mysql server will actually rollback a transaction?

Comment: Stephen, I found I didn't have "require 'test_help'" in test_helper for whatever reason. Thanks for responding and getting my brain working, I marked your answer as the correct one so you can get the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyISAM db engine, this is pretty normal, as it doesn't support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are expecting tests to be wrapped in transactions and yet not using rails,
but instead using ActiveSupport and ActiveRecord on their own, you should manually include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures:

```
ActiveSupport::TestCase.include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures
```

Otherwise transaction functionality including  **use_transactional_fixtures/use_transactional_tests** will not be defined.